# Spark results accessible through API

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

We really would want to get an input here about how the results from a Spark Query will be accessible to a web-application. Given Spark is a well used in the industry I would have thought that this part would have lots of answers/tutorials about it, but I didnt find anything.

Here are a few options that come to mind

1. Spark results are saved in another DB ( perhaps a traditional one) and a request for query returns the new table name for access through a paginated query. That seems doable, although a bit convoluted as we need to handle the completion of the query.
2. Spark results are pumped into a  messaging queue from which a socket server like connection is made.

What confuses me is that other connectors to spark, like those for Tableau, using something like JDBC should have all the data (not the top 500 that we typically can get via Livy or other REST interfaces to Spark). How do those connectors get all the data through a single connection.

Can someone with expertise help in that sense?

Comment: I would guess spark isn't widely used for web-applications because spark has quite a big latency which makes it not suitable for user-interaction.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I wouldn't forget about the lack of built-in security.

Comment: That is why I plan to not have the Spark exposed directly. The security will be handled by another API layer, but the point is that its used for Big Data analysis in a bunch of platform --- how is that exposed.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way I think would be to use Livy, as you mention. Since it's a REST API you wouldn't expect to get a JSON response containing the full result (could be gigabytes of data, after all).

Rather, you'd use pagination with `?from=500` and issue multiple requests to get the number of rows you need. A web application would only need to display or visualize a small part of the data at a time anyway.

But from what you mentioned in your comment to Raphael Roth, you didn't mean to call this API directly from the web app (with good reason). So you'll have an API layer that is called by the web app and which then invokes Spark. But in this case, you can still use Livy+pagination to achieve what you want, unless you specifically need to have the full result available. If you do need the full results generated on the backend, you could design the Spark queries so they materialize the result (ideally to cloud storage) and then all you need is to have your API layer access the storage where Spark writes the results.